# How can i run Bulk insert from client file path in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to write a web application for the client user to select a file from client system and
start uploading that file to server with bulk insert,i have written this query:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                    String paht = Server.MapPath("~/") + filename;
                    string bulkInsertQuery = "BULK INSERT Table_1 from '" + paht + "' WITH( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',CODEPAGE = '1256'); ";
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(bulkInsertQuery, con))
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();
                        }//end of using
                    }//end using 1
```

But when run that code,i get this error:

```
{"Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.\r\nThe OLE DB provider \"BULK\" for linked server \"(null)\" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.\r\nCannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider \"BULK\" for linked server \"(null)\"."}
```

what is happening ?how can i solve this?thanks.

Comment: First you should try your query in your database manager to be sure whatever the text the file contains is valid. If you get the same error then you found your problem.

Comment: @avi hi my friend ,i try that query on the sql server,and every thing ok,i think file path is problem.

Comment: hmm...if you are sure the file is saved after FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename); (you could also do a check if there is any file to upload with FileUpload1.HasFile before doing the SaveAs) you could check your variable paht with File.Exists(paht)

Comment: when you tried your query on sql server, have you used the content of the variable paht? Note that the file should be saved on the same machine your sql server instance is installed